# How to hide mouse cursor while using HUD in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity-2d, hud

I want the mouse cursor to hide when I press the HUD key <kbd>Alt</kbd>. It should toggle back on if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> again or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Problem:**

When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> showing the HUD, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> should execute the first result. However, it will instead select whatever random thing the mouse happens to be over. Example: You press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key then type "mu" then enter. This would normally mute the audio, unless your mouse happens to be over one of the other results in the HUD.

Is there a workaround or solution for this?

edit: This problem is for Unity 2D.

Comment: That's right! It's happening in Unity 2d only.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried it was just my computer. So it's all Unity 2d, I guess. I wonder if this is merits a bug report.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).